# Why can't Java IO implement async reading?

Tags: java, io

In Java IO, we use Stream and Reader while in NIO we use Channel, Selector.

They both do the same thing, but the structure is totally different.

So why they don't write a new Stream like "AsyncStream" or a Reader like "AsyncReader" to implement what NIO have implemented. If so, we only have one structure and it's beautiful.

So why Java IO cannot implement async reading?
 What are the difficulties to implement async reading using Java IO ?

Or what is the advantage of writing a new framework instead of using the existing one?

Comment: Java I/O *can* implement async reading, and it does so via [`java.nio.AsynchronousChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannel.html). If you're asking why it couldn't have all been squeezed into the `java.io` streams paradigm, that's a different question from what it actually says above, but for one thing `java.io.OutputStream.write()` returns `void`, not a count: for another, there are no `Futures` or `CompletionHandlers` in `java.io`; and for another, a stream is not an asynchronous source by definition.

Comment: They can define a new interface called AsyncStream whose write method will return a async object. Based on the new interface we can implement AsyncFileInputStream and AsyncReader. Maybe the new classes are something like NIO, but we will only have Stream and Reader which we all understood their meaning if we implement async methods using the same structure as Stream, we don't have to learn what is a Channel and what is a Selector, which will waste some time.

Comment: My question is about how to use the same structure of Stream to implement NIO, not to use the exactly same interface.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your idea in the comment above, but I'm afraid that there is insufficient detail to understand it as a proposal.  Without that, it is impossible to make a judgment on whether it would work or not.

However, there are a couple of points that can be made in response:

- IF Java was a shiny new (and unreleased) language, THEN they could improve on the I/O API design in a few areas.
- In addition, IF someone came up with a well-considered, fleshed out API design that combined sync and async capabilities, THEN that could be considered.

But Java is NOT a shiny new language.  It is an old programming language, with billions of lines of source code written in it.  The kind of change that you are contemplating on a central API *would* either create huge binary compatibility problems for Oracle's paying customers, or it would lead to a huge legacy code problem.  It simply would not happen.

Setting that aside, if you attempted to merge sync and async capabilities into a single API, you *risk* creating a situation where:

- custom stream types need to implement a lot of extra functionality, and / or
- the merger leads to unanticipated performance issues.

Now these concerns *may not be warranted*.

However, we cannot tell without seeing a concrete API design proposal *and* an implementation to try out for usability and performance.  Bear in mind that the original elegant API design for I/O streams and (then) readers / writers *actually* turned out to have a variety of problems.  These did not become apparent until people used the APIs in production code.  For example:

- character encoding concerns lead to the introduction of `Reader` / `Writer` in Java 1.1.
- performance analyse identified that memory memory-to-memory copying was a problem, leading to the introduction of `Buffer` and so on.

In summary, it is really hard to design a good I/O API ... and Java is unlikely to change anyway.